# Property Picture in Image1 had an invalid file reference

Tags: svn, vb6

I am working on my office visual basic project and I created a form with some picture files with .gif format added in it in design time. I uploaded the images to the Project's images folder and then attached them to the UI from that location. I used with both Image and PictureBox to add the pictures.I tested the code and committed the code to SVN.

Then I got a checkout of the project and when I try to run the code, I got an error with the form and the form log said "**Property Picture in Image1 had an invalid file reference.**" for all the images I added to the form.

I even tried with ImageList, I added the relevant pictures to the ImageList and in runtime, I attached pictures to the Images/PictureBoxes and do the commit. Still the same issue is occurring.

Can anybody help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Images references are stored in the form's .frx file. Is that file included in your source repository?

Comment: I have forgotten to add the .frx file to the SVN after I did modifications in the form and now I have fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images references are stored in the form's .frx file. If you did not add the .frx file to source control, it will be missing when you check code out of the repository, which will result in this issue (among many others).